# How to update UI with Parse data, outside of the main thread (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform, pfquery

I am new to Parse and databases, and I am currently confused.

On the view, there are 4 buttons and a label. This is my code (sorry it is very messy):

I have just heard that UI updates and actions should not be done within the main thread, because `PFQuery` does not support the UI directly.

And obviously, the log executes a error: `Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.`

I would like to use the queried data outside of the block to update `label.text`, so how can I set the data (value) so I can use it throughout the other methods within the code?

I know it's a very rudimentary question, but I would be really happy if somebody can help me out with the solution for this.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DataClass"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSString *getTheStr1 = object[@"A"];
        NSString *getTheStr2 = object[@"B"];
        NSString *getTheStr3 = object[@"C"];
        NSString *getTheStr4 = object[@"D"];

           //when I press a button, each shows a different text on the label.
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        switch ([button tag]) {
            case 1:
                Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr1];
                break;

            case 2:
                Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr2];
                break;

            case 3:
                Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr3];
                break;

            case 4:
                Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr4];
        }
    }
}];
```

Thank you.

I come from my previous question
[How can I retrieve multiple data simultaneously? (Parse DB, iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502559/how-can-i-retrieve-multiple-data-simultaneously-parse-db-ios)

Comment: UI modification can only be done in Main Thread. When you want to refresh it, do it in main thread.

Comment: You can put the object in a property or send it around as any other object. If you have a property PFObject *dataClass, you can do this in the block: self.dataClass = object;

Comment: Ohhhh I finally understand how everything works. Thank you everybody.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve multiple data at the same time from Parse? (Obj-C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530315/how-to-retrieve-multiple-data-at-the-same-time-from-parse-obj-c)

Answer (score 0):

You got it the other way around: UI can only be updated on the main thread. You should try to avoid doing all other kind of long running operations (such as network requests) on the main thread so you don't block it.

Your code seems ok, what is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So does that mean I cannot call the queried data to another method?     I would also be very happy if you could consider my previous question, because I am completely lost...

Comment: You can send the received object around, don't know if that's what you are asking. [self myOtherMethod:object]

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. Thank you, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried GCD ?

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DataClass"];

    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
    NSString *getTheStr1 = object[@"A"];
    NSString *getTheStr2 = object[@"B"];
    NSString *getTheStr3 = object[@"C"];
    NSString *getTheStr4 = object[@"D"];

       //when I press a button, each shows a different text on the label.
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch ([button tag]) {
        case 1:
            Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr1];
            break;

        case 2:
            Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr2];
            break;

        case 3:
            Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr3];
            break;

        case 4:
            Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getTheStr4];
        }
    }
}];
});
```

Comment: This will fire a background thread, which will again fire a background thread (since getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock does that). No need to use GCD with Parse.

Comment: Using getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock will make sure he doesn't use the main thread. If he still gets that message, it is from another part of her code.